# Default value for PivotChart Report Filter/Page Field

Tags: excel, vba

I'm generating a pivot chart in Excel 2002 with a macro, using a date field as the chart report filter (setting the field orientation to xlPageField). I would like to set the default selected value of this pivotfield to the most recent value in the date field. What's the right syntax for doing that in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you loop through all the items for that pagefield? Here's for a pivot table but getting it to work for a chart shouldn't be big deal:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim fld As PivotField
    Dim itm As PivotItem
    Dim m As Variant

    Set pvt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1)
    Set fld = pvt.PageFields(1)

    m = fld.PivotItems(1)
    For Each itm In fld.PivotItems
        If itm.Value > m Then m = itm.Value
    Next itm

    fld.CurrentPage = m
End Sub
```

Comment: My alternative was to get the most recent date with an SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to select the cell after you have dynamically created the chart?

Something like:

```
Dim value As Date
value = "1-apr-09"
Dim row As Integer
row = 0

Dim keeplooping As Boolean
keeplooping = True
While (keeplooping)
    row = row + 1
    If Range("B" & row).value = value Then
        keeplooping = False
        Range("B" & row).Select
        MsgBox ("found it")
    ElseIf Range("B" & row).value = "" Then
        keeplooping = False
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    End If
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

*chartObject*.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("*fieldName*").CurrentPage = "*fieldValue*"

That's from Excel 2003 but I presume 2002 will be similar

Comment: Yes, you're right, but what I really wanted to calculate in VBA is the "fieldValue". I've solved my problem by creating a separate sql query to find the maximum date value but I was wondering how I could have done that by just querying the pivot table